# Identify Component with Markings

Tags: laser

I can't identify this component.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you give us a photo of the whole thing, and show the silk screen around it? Are we hiding something?

Answer (score 2):

It’s a Bourns 3224W trimmer potentiometer. 503 = 50kOhms.